# Populate an array from an other array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have an issue tryng to populate an array based on an other array... let me explain you the problem

I have this array

```
$contents = (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Text1
            [slug] => text1
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Text2
            [slug] => text2
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Text3
            [slug] => text3
        )
 [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Text3
            [slug] => text3
        )
```

)

Then I created a variable $st within an array from the above slugs

```
foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
        $st[$key] = $value['slug'];
    }
```

Then I extracted the uri segment from inside code igniter with

```
$path = $this->uri->segment(1);
```

Then I took off the value of $path from the $st array with:

```
if(($key = array_search($path, $st)) !== false) {
        unset($st[$key]);
    }
```

Then I put the $st array in order with

```
$stack = array_values($st);
```

Ultimately I have looped through the new array and see if there was the value inside, if true I pushed inside the relative array like so:

```
 $per[] = array();
 while($i < count($contents)) {
        if(in_array($path, $stack) === FALSE) {
            array_push($per, $percorsi[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

At the end i have an empty array, if i put if is not in array i have all four element in the new array.

I hope I have explained me good.

Thanks for the help

Cheers

Comment: In the while loop I have put array_push($per, $percorsi[$i]); but in I have made a mistake. in the code is like so :
array_push($per, $contents[$i]);

Comment: Instead why not - `if(!in_array($path, $stack))`?

Comment: It gave me the all four elements without skipping the one with $path value

Answer (score 0):

Change this. As you are defing multi array. Thus value is not inserted

```
 $per = [];
```

Comment: True. but again it return all four elements... it is like doesn't make the if statement

Comment: Do one thing remove that false and in else part push to array. Echo something in side the if statement

Comment: does not work...
if(in_array($path, $stack))  in the loop is always true or false for all 4 cases. but there is an in_array() with $path = text1 and $stack = array('text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4);

It's weird tough

Comment: Can you print path and stack and show the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution changing a bit the workflow like so:

```
$per = array();
    $path = $this->uri->segment(1);

    foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
        $stack[$key] = $value['slug'];
    }

    $i=0;
    while($i <= 3) {
        if($path !== $stack[$i]) {
            array_push($per, $contents[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution:

```
   $contents = array ( 
 0 => Array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Text1',
            'slug' => 'text1',
        ),
 1 => Array
        (
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Text2',
            'slug' => 'text2'
        ),
 2 => Array
        (
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => 'Text3',
            'slug' => 'text3'
        ),
 3 => Array
        (
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => 'Text3',
            'slug' => 'text3'
        )

);

$path = 'text3'; //$this->uri->segment(1);
foreach($contents as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($path, $val)){
        unset($contents[$key]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($contents);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2JLd1)